# Using scalaz-stream to calculate a digest

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

So I was wondering how I might use scalaz-stream to generate the digest of a file using java.security.MessageDigest?

I would like to do this using a constant memory buffer size (for example 4KB). I think I understand how to start with reading the file, but I am struggling to understand how to:

1) call `digest.update(buf)` for each 4KB which effectively is a side-effect on the Java MessageDigest instance, which I guess should happen inside the scalaz-stream framework.

2) finally call `digest.digest()` to receive back the calculated digest from within the scalaz-stream framework some how?

I think I understand kinda how to start:

```
import scalaz.stream._
import java.security.MessageDigest

val f = "/a/b/myfile.bin"
val bufSize = 4096

val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")

Process.constant(bufSize).toSource
  .through(io.fileChunkR(f, bufSize))
```

But then I am stuck!
Any hints please? I guess it must also be possible to wrap the creation, update, retrieval (of actual digest calculatuon) and destruction of digest object in a scalaz-stream Sink or something, and then call `.to()` passing in that Sink? Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology, I am completely new to using scalaz-stream. I have been through a few of the examples but am still struggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since version 0.4 scalaz-stream contains processes to calculate digests. They are available in the [`hash`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/blob/master/src/main/scala/scalaz/stream/hash.scala) module and use `java.security.MessageDigest` under the hood. Here is a minimal example how you could use them:

```
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.stream._

object Sha1Sum extends App {
  val fileName = "testdata/celsius.txt"
  val bufferSize = 4096

  val sha1sum: Task[Option[String]] =
    Process.constant(bufferSize)
      .toSource
      .through(io.fileChunkR(fileName, bufferSize))
      .pipe(hash.sha1)
      .map(sum => s"${sum.toHex}  $fileName")
      .runLast

  sha1sum.run.foreach(println)
}
```

The `update()` and `digest()` calls are all contained inside the `hash.sha1` `Process1`.

Comment: That is very very cool :-)

So if that didn't already exist, it looks like I needed to create a Process, and then call `.pipe` on it instead of creating a Sink. I assume that is because a Sink cannot emit a result whereas a Process can?

Comment: @adamretter `Sink[F[_],O]` is a type alias for `Process[F, O => F[Unit]]`, so they are a source of effectful functions that return `Unit`. As you demonstrated, you can send the input `ByteVector`s to a `Sink` but there is no way get the final digest back out of it. The processes in `hash` are `Process1`s: they can consume and emit values. The chunks of the file are piped into the `sha1` to update the digest and when there are no more input values it emits just the final digest.

Answer (score 0):

So I have something working, but it could probably be improved:

```
import java.io._
import java.security.MessageDigest
import resource._
import scodec.bits.ByteVector
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz.concurrent.Task
import scalaz.stream._
import scalaz.stream.io._

val f = "/a/b/myfile.bin"
val bufSize = 4096

val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")

def _digestResource(md: => MessageDigest): Sink[Task,ByteVector] =
      resource(Task.delay(md))(md => Task.delay(()))(
        md => Task.now((bytes: ByteVector) => Task.delay(md.update(bytes.toArray))))

Process.constant(4096).toSource
    .through(fileChunkR(f.getAbsolutePath, 4096))
    .to(_digestResource(md))
    .run
    .run

md.digest()
```

However, it seems to me that there should be a cleaner way to do this, by moving the creation of the `MessageDigest` inside the scalaz-stream stuff and have the final `.run` yield the `md.digest()`.

Better answers welcome...